# What does this equation mean/represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, atomic-physics, scattering-cross-section

The other day I was wandering around my brother's high school and I saw the following blackboard with a person's face and an equation at his left.
The drawn person I recognised to be Ettore Majorana, the theoretical physicist.

Yet I did not understand the equation. Seems like a sort of scattering cross section but which one? If it is. Anyone can help me in understanding the meaning?

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but do you think the tone of your comment will get you lots of sympathies?

Comment: @noah No, you're right I deleted it. It did just upset me for a while... Anyway I hope someone will answer because in my humble opinion questions like this are interesting for the curious ones over here...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Did it in many ways. No result.

Comment: I don't know enough history to associate the formula with Majorana, but the probability density of s-wave hydrogen-like atom wavefunctions at the origin is $-Z^2\alpha^2mc/2n^2$,  so $dE/dn= Z^2 \alpha^2mc^2/n^3$, while $\psi(0)^2\propto 1/(\pi n^3 a^3)$, *a* being the Bohr radius so $n^3$ cancels in concatenating these two formulas. Maybe it is a practical relation M first noticed.